# HTTP Video Stream frame by frame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

I have HTTP Video stream, so i want to receive frame by frame from it. I have seen this AVCaptureSessionDelegate method, but this is only for camera video:

```
    - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput 
    didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer 
   fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection 
    { 
    }
```

I have also read about iFrameExtractor but this is solution for video file, not stream. Is there some solution about this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I know you can get single snapshots from the videos that the iPhone camera take but I don't think thats what your getting at. You could use ffmpeg like iframeextractor does because it does work equally well with files. Back in 2010 we were developing an app that played  mpeg, avi, divx, xvid and many other formats. So what you ask is certainly possible.